# Random Walk With Fair Coin Finding the limit

Tags: probability, limits, statistics

Let us $S_n = X_1 +\cdots +X_n $ where $X_i$ is 1 if the outcome is heads and $X_i$ is -1 if the outcome is tail with a fair coin flip of n time. Find the $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{S_n}{n}$. Ok. The answer is given as Zero. but I can't convince myself to access by understanding it. My thinking is that:
We first find the $\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n$, which is undefined (if I still have some correct understanding of limit.) How come the limit of $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{S_n}{n}$ is zero since the limit of  $\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n$ is already undefined? Any hints or different perceptive to look at it?

Comment: Check out the alternating series test for intuition.

Comment: You need some more machinery to answer this properly...

Comment: What you need to prove is that for ae. $\omega$, ${S_n(\omega) \over n} \to 0$. There are sequences for which the limit does not exist. Durrett's book "Probability: Theory and Examples" has a slick proof based on $EX^4 < \infty$ and the Borel Cantelli lemma.

Comment: Actually the limit is zero *with probability one*. You can't be sure the limit is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probability of heads is 1/2 and same for tails. So for a large number of trials there should be equal number of heads and tails thus the Sn becomes zero that is why limit is zero.